# RestClient post request in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, rest, ruby-on-rails-5, rest-client

RestClient post request

I tried post request couple ways

```
@user =  {name: 'xxxxxx', email: 'xxxxxx@gmail.com', password: 'qwertyqqq'}
RestClient.post 'http://localhost:4123/api/users?token=<token>', @user

RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post, url: 'http://localhost:4123/api/v1/users', token: '<token>', payload: '@user', headers: {"Content-Type" => "application/json"})
```

Error: RestClient::BadRequest: 400 Bad Request or RestClient::UnprocessableEntity: 422 Unprocessable Entity

Success cases

When i made a get request with rest client and with curl is just fine.

```
RestClient.get 'http://localhost:4123/api/v1/users?token=<token>'
```

With curl:

Get request:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:4123/api/v1/users/1?token=<token>
```

Post request for helpy:

```
curl -d '{"name":"xxxx","email":"xxxx@gmail.com","password":"12345678", "admin": true, "role":"admin"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:4123/api/v1/users?token=<token>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the `CURL` version and the `RestClient` version is that in the `CURL` version you send a `JSON` string as payload but in the `RestClient` sends the string `'@user'`.

It should be fine when you actually send JSON:

```
RestClient.post(
  "http://localhost:4123/api/v1/users?token=<token>", 
  @user.to_json, 
  { content_type: :json, accept: :json }
)
```

Comment: Great Thank you. It just fine.